# Angular weirdness: how can one object attribute change an attribute on two different objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, reference, angular-ngmodel

I'm building a website using Angularjs in which I've got a list of objects:

```
$scope.fieldsToShow = [
    {
        "fields": {},
        "type": "LOGGED_IN"
    },
    {
        "fields": {},
        "type": "PERSONAL",
        "user": 2,
        "name": "Rick Astley"
    }
];
```

I then select one of the objects into a variable:

```
var $scope.currentObject = $scope.fieldsToShow[1];
```

to let the user change it using the some checkboxes:

```
<input ng-model="currentObject.fields.a" type="checkbox">
```

which changes both `$scope.currentObject`:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "a": true
    },
    "type": "PERSONAL",
    "user": 2,
    "name": "Rick Astley"
}
```

and the original object in `$scope.fieldsToShow`:

```
$scope.fieldsToShow = [
    {
        "fields": {},
        "type": "LOGGED_IN"
    },
    {
        "fields": {
            "a": true
        },
        "type": "PERSONAL",
        "user": 2,
        "name": "Rick Astley"
    }
];
```

I then change the `$scope.currentObject` to the first object in the array:

```
$scope.currentObject = $scope.fieldsToShow[0];
```

and I click the checkbox again. As expected this also adds `"a": true` to the fields object of the first object in the `$scope.fieldsToShow` list. So far so good.

I now want to add an object within the `fields` object. So I created another checkbox:

```
<input ng-model="currentObject.fields.anInnerObject.val" type="checkbox">
```

I then change to the PERSONAL object again (`$scope.currentObject = $scope.fieldsToShow[1];`) and click the checkbox. As expected this changes both the `$scope.currentObject`:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "anInnerObject": {
            "val": true
        }
    },
    "type": "PERSONAL",
    "user": 2,
    "name": "Rick Astley"
}
```

and the original object in `$scope.fieldsToShow`:

```
$scope.fieldsToShow = [
    {
        "fields": {},
        "type": "LOGGED_IN"
    },
    {
        "fields": {
            "anInnerObject": {
                "val": true
            }
        },
        "type": "PERSONAL",
        "user": 2,
        "name": "Rick Astley"
    }
];
```

I then change to the `LOGGED_IN` object again (`$scope.currentObject = $scope.fieldsToShow[0];`) and click the checkbox again. And here is where it gets tricky. As expected it changes the `$scope.currentObject`:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "anInnerObject": {
            "val": true
        }
    },
    "type": "LOGGED_IN",
}
```

it also changes the original object in `$scope.fieldsToShow` (still as expected), BUT it ALSO changes the value of `"anInnerObject"` in the PERSONAL object to the boolean `true`:

```
$scope.fieldsToShow = [
    {
        "fields": {
            "anInnerObject": {
                "val": true  // This changed, which I understand
            }
        },
        "type": "LOGGED_IN"
    },
    {
        "fields": {
            "anInnerObject": true  // BUT WHY this value also change? And why did it become true?
        },
        "type": "PERSONAL",
        "user": 2,
        "name": "Rick Astley"
    }
];
```

How in the world can this happen?! I've been banging my head against the wall for hours, tried a million things and asked a colleague for help, but I simply can't find why this behaves like it does?

Does anybody know how this can happen? All tips are welcome!

Comment: What I'm missing from your description is how fieldsToShow and its contents are created. From everything you've described it sounds as if both anInnerObjects are the same instance instance rather then different objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand that both both `$scope.currentObject` and the *original* object in `$scope.fieldsToShow` the **same** object. Both are just references to the same memory location. This is how references to non-primitive types work in Javasript.

If you want to have truly separate *different* object you need to clone it before using:

```
var $scope.currentObject = angular.copy($scope.fieldsToShow[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I understand that it are references to the same object. I don't want a truly separate object because I do want it to change in the object in `$scope.fieldsToShow` as well. I added another comment in the last code in the question to clarify the exact trouble which I'm having. The problem is that it changes a value in BOTH objects in the list, instead of just one of them. Any idea how this can happen?

Comment: *"Any idea how this can happen?"*. It's not possible with what you posted. I assume something else interfere what you don't show in the question. Can you replicate the issue in the demo?

Comment: "Can you replicate the issue in the demo?" => I will try. There is quite some code around it so it is not so easy to replicate without copying the whole page of js, which would make it very hard for you to understand. I'll update the question and let you know once I managed to create a demo of the issue..

Comment: So this is the problem. You have to much code and for sure something causes this behaviour. As I said what you are describing is not possible with what you posted. But working on simplified demo will likely reveal the problem to you, so it's useful.

Comment: Ok, I found the answer. You were right after all: "I have too much code", dammit.. :-) In the end I found a piece of code (which I even wrote myself) that changes all the values of the PERSONAL views to true if the user set that value in "LOGGED_IN" to true (for some weird business logic reason). Excuse me for bothering you with this stupidity. I thank you for your precious time anyway. People like you make the world a better place.. :-)

Comment: No, problem, glad you figured it out!